# CoinMarketCap API / Cannot read properties of undefined 'quote'

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, cryptocurrency, coinmarketcap

I am trying to fetch the last quote data from CoinMarketCap using their API, into a GoogleSheets document to manage my portfolio.
I am using Google Apps Script to fetch the data, but I keep getting an “undefined ‘quote’” error.

*Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'quote')
coin_price @ Code.gs:37*

Am I missing something in my code?
Am I missing something in the API documentation?

Below you will find the function I've been using until today, that I got the error.

Thanks in advance!

CMC API documentation
https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#operation/getV2CryptocurrencyQuotesLatest

```js
function coin_price() {
  const myGoogleSheetName =
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Coins");

  const coinMarketCapAPICall = {
    method: "GET",

    uri: "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest",

    qs: {
      start: "1",

      limit: "200",

      convert: "USD",
    },

    headers: { "X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY": "here-I-insert-my-API" },

    json: true,

    gzip: true,
  };

  // Get the coins I want from spreadsheet

  let myCoinSymbols = [];

  const getValues = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();

  for (let i = 0; i < getValues.length; i++) {
    // 1 = Column B in the spreadsheet.

    const coinSymbol = getValues[i][1];

    if (coinSymbol) {
      myCoinSymbols.push(coinSymbol);
    }
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < myCoinSymbols.length; i++) {
    const ticker = myCoinSymbols[i];

    const coinMarketCapUrl = `https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest?symbol=${ticker}`;

    const result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(coinMarketCapUrl, coinMarketCapAPICall);

    const txt = result.getContentText();

    const d = JSON.parse(txt);

    const row = i + 2;

    myGoogleSheetName
      .getRange(row, 12)
      .setValue(d.data[ticker].quote.USD.price);
  }
}
```

I tried to follow the documentation but couldn't find the source of the error.

Comment: Although I'm not sure about the error line, if your error occurs at `myGoogleSheetName.getRange(row, 12).setValue(d.data[ticker].quote.USD.price)`, can you provide your sample values of `txt` and `ticker`?

Comment: Hi Tanaike!
The ticker value is the coin ticker (e.g.: "BTC")
After tweaking the setValue and hitting different types of error (always around that same line ("USD is not defined", or "quote is not defined") I decided to solve the issue using an external app ("API connector") with an alternative API service (Coingecko instead of CoinMarketCap) and now everything seems to work.

Thanks for your time to answer! Really appreciate it.